# Q pattern for many queued operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm writing a small script for node.js to read a bunch of image names (2.5k) from a file, resize the images and output them to a directory.  My naïve way leads to running out of file handles:

```
//get the list of images, one per line in the file
var imgs = file.split('\n');
//keep track of how many images we've processed
var done = imgs.length;
var deferred = Q.defer();

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  (function resizeImg(img) {
    //open the file for writing the resized image to
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream('images/' + img);

    stream
      .on('open', function () {
        //now that it's opened, resize the source image, and write it
        //out to the stream
        gm(img)
          .resize(200, 200)
          .write(stream, function (err) {
            //we're finished writing - if there was an error, reject
            //otherwise, we can resolve the promise if this was the last image
            if (err)
              deferred.reject(err);
            else if (--done <= 0)
              deferred.resolve();
          });
      });
  })(imgs[i]);
}

return deferred.promise;
```

Really what I need to do is queue all the resize operations and run them sequentially so that it doesn't open all the files at the same time, but I'm not sure how to do this.  Is there a standard pattern for this sort of thing?

Comment: How many files can you open at the same time? Can you detect (and do you want to adapt) this dynamically? Or just run them one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like this:

```
//get the list of images, one per line in the file
var imgs = file.split('\n');
//keep track of how many images we've processed
var done = imgs.length;

//Store an array of functions to be executed in sequence
var funcArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  //push a promise function onto the array
  funcArr.push((function resizeImg(img) {
    return function () {
        var deferred = Q.defer();

        //open the file for writing the resized image to
        var stream = fs.createWriteStream('images/' + img);

        stream
          .on('open', function () {
            //now that it's opened, resize the source image, and write it
            //out to the stream
            gm(img)
              .resize(200, 200)
              .write(stream, function (err) {
                //we're finished writing - if there was an error, reject
                //otherwise, we can resolve the promise if this was the last image
                if (err)
                  deferred.reject(err);
                else
                  deferred.resolve();
              });
          });

          return deferred.promise;
    }
  })(imgs[i]));
}

//Sequences as described at http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/
var result = Q();
funcArr.forEach(function (f) {
    result = result.then(f, function (reason) {
        //Default error handler for each image in the sequence that does a reject
    });
});

//At this point result is a promise that will be resolved when all images have processed
return result;
```

Each iteration of the for loop pushes a function that returns a promise into the funcArr array. Q is used after the for loop to chain promises together for sequencing. This should ensure that one image is processed before moving to the next.

Comment: Thanks! I went with more or less this, only in a more functional-programming-esque way, just as an experiment.  Going with example on the Q github readme which you linked to, I mapped the resize function over the image array then reduced it as follows: `file.split('\n').map(resizeImg).reduce(Q.when, Q())`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier, though not essential, to separate out the resizing process into a function that returns a promise.

This allows you to see the wood for the trees in the main routine.

```
function resizeImages(file) {

    //An inner utility function that returns a function that does the hard work and, importantly, that returns promise.
    function resize(img) {
        return function() {
            var deferred = Q.defer(),
                stream = fs.createWriteStream('images/' + img);
            stream.on('open', function() {
                gm(img).resize(200, 200).write(stream, deferred.resolve);//Always resolve, even if error is reported, thus allowing the .then chain to continue.
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

    var p = Q();//resolved starter promise

    //main routine - build a .then chain
    for(var imgs=file.split("\n"), i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
        p = p.then(resize(imgs[i])).then(function(err) {
            //Yup, we're handling reported errors in the success handler!
            if(err) {
                //Handle error here.
                //throw(something) to stop the process or don't throw(anything) to continue.
            }
        });
    };
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Handling errors in the success handler looks like an antipattern. Better build the promise correctly.

Comment: What on earth is an "antipattern" Bergi? You can have better or worse, but anti ...! The point is that only those errors reported to the `.on('open')` callback as `err` are handled in this way. For sure you could route such errors down the fail path but there's no particular logic to doing so in the callback rather than in the `.then()` success handler. You would just bulk up the code for no particular benefit other than to avoid an antipattern (doh!). I prefer the concise nature of `deferred.resolve`.

Comment: antipattern, code smell, bad practise, whatever - even if I have use wrong terminology, it is definitely not clean. If you really want to route errors trough the success handler before, that should stay within the `resize` function. For conciseness, just use `.write(stream, deferred.makeNodeResolver())`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I agree it is often better to separate out the function for clarity, and had only put it inline for question conciseness. I'm afraid I would tend to agree with @Bergi here on error handling though, and since Patrick got there first I've given him the answer.